# Make all tabs of Accordion open on Init

Tags: flex4, accordion

Does Flex 4.5 allow to open all tabs of accordion on somehting like Init();

I know that it was not possible with Flex 3, we needed to create custom component. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

After reading about this I found that I have to create my own custom accordion.